# Convergence of an implicitly defined series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is a sequence of numbers $a_n\in (0,1)$ with the following property. There exist constants $C>1$, $u>t \in (0,1)$, such that for every $n \geq 1$:
$$
a_{n-1}-a_{n} \leq Ca_n^{t}+ Ca_n^{u}.
$$

**Question:** Show that there exists a power $s \in (0,t)$ such that
$$
\sum_1^\infty (a_{n-1}-a_n)^s < +\infty.
$$

The question is about generalizing the following:

**Example:** The sequence $a_n=n^{-1/t}$ satisfies $a_{n-1}-a_{n} \leq Ca_n^{t} = C n^{-(1+1/t)}$, so the above series converges for $s \in (t/(t+1),t)$.